# How to pass a string with place holders from one notebook to another notebook in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to declare a variable as string with place holders in notebook1 and calling that variable in notebook2 in spark.sql. But getting syntax error at {'

in notebook1:

```
qry = "SELECT {id} from {stage_table}"
```

in notebook2:

```
%run ./notebook1

df =  spark.sql(f"qry")
```

Note: I have to pass the values "id" and "stage_table" in notebook2 to the query

but this didn't worked. getting syntax error (ParseException:
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'qry'.)

Any suggestion how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to declare the variables id and stage_table in notebook 2, you cannot use them in notebook 1.
What you can do is to use replace:

in notebook 1:

```
qry = "SELECT AAAA from BBBB"
```

in notebook 2:

```
%run ./notebook1
id = "some_name"
stage_table = "table_name"
qry_replaced = qry.replace("AAAA",id).replace("BBBB",stage_table)
df =  spark.sql(qry_replaced)
```

The reason to use AAAA is its unlikely to appear in a regular text.